# Looping with ranges not allowing Range(Cells,Cells) only Range("A:A")

Tags: vba, excel

**Background:**

I have an array of 7 x 30 cells to loop through.  For each of the 30 columns (Dim j), I am looping through rows (Dim i) 1 to see if a value is present and if so start copying the range of rows 2 through 7.

In attempting to use (e.g.):

```
Sheets("NAME").Range(Cells(i+1,1),Cells(i+7,1)).Copy
```

I am getting a 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error, that I have been able to alleviate using:

```
Sheets("NAME").Range("A" & i+1 & ":A" & i+7 & ").Copy
```

Error on line from my code:

```
Sheets("RM").Range(Cells(i + 6, 2), Cells(i + 13, 2)).Copy
```

---

**Issue:**

This has worked for items with known columns, but I am unsure how to proceed for a variable column, as well.  I know that this doesn't work:

```
Sheets("NAME").Range(Cells(i+1,j),Cells(i+7,j)).Copy
```

I would need to find a way to fit this Range model without Cells to work for j, a variable column.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to make this work using Range without using Cells?

My only guess is the following, which I believe uses incorrect syntax:

```
Sheets("NAME").Range(Columns(j) & i+1 & ":" & Columns(j) & i+1).Copy
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: added the error 1004 name to this *Issues* section.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, I missed that I only listed "an error" not that it was a 1004 error on that line.  Updated the post, and added the exact line I received the error for (not a re-hash for the post).

Comment: Then as the answer below shows you need to add the same parent to the `Cells()` as you did the `Range()`: `Sheets("NAME").Range(Sheets("NAME").Cells(i+1,1),Sheets("NAME").Cells(i+7,1)).Copy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try prefacing your `Cells(` call with the sheet i.e. `Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2))`

When you omit the sheet in a call to `Cells` or `Range` then it will default to a reference to the currently selected sheet, so if you're calling `Sheets(Unselected Sheet).Range(Cells(1, 1))` it gets confused between which sheet you're referring to.

Comment: The problem is exactly what I've said in my answer. You need to preface your call to `Cells` with the name of the sheet, like `Sheets("NAME").Range(Sheets("NAME").Cells(i+1,1), Sheets("NAME").Cells(i+7,1)).Copy`

Comment: Got'cha, I didn't read that correctly and Scott helped re-direct more to what you were saying.  Thank you!  Marked as answer.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it very well it's a little awkward to explain how excel is viewing the references etc. Good luck with the rest of your program!

Comment: Thanks man; was removing the first comment I gave you, just as you responded to it.  It made sense, I just got lost on the carry-over of lines when I was looking at the first paragraph you gave.  My fault, you were solid.